# Using the same code across multiple models and controllers (or replacing just the model name)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dry

I'm fairly new to Rails and try to be very dry with my data.

I have a few models, controllers and views which are EXACTLY the same. The models use id, name, the controllers retrieve only via the id, as well as always getting the same objects from another table, and the actions are exactly the same too.

---UPDATE ---The tables exist as part of a legacy system, so I can't recreate it with just a single table.

It seems not-DRY (wet?) to have all 3 models, 3 controllers and 9 views which do exactly the same thing.

Is there a way to pass in a table name as a variable, for these instances?

If this is not recommended in rails, can you explain why not?

Comment: Why not use Single Table Inheritance if all the models are (almost) exactly the same?

Comment: unfortunately, the tables are being used by another app, so I can't recreate it as a single table inheritance. I'll update the question, should have mentioned that initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way to dry this up a bit is to create common partials for these views and render them.

If you want to dry up your controllers/models, you can extract your logic to another class which they all happily inherit from/require.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit yoka? when you say extract into another class, should that class exist as a model? helper? inside an already existing model? I assume with 'require', I would just use require 'className' in the top of my controller or model? is that right?

Comment: Take a look at how to write rails plugins that extend controller functionality, that way you can write generic actions and use those in your controllers that need similar functionality. [http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html)

Comment: The plugins stuff seemed quite a bit of overhead what I ended up doing was putting everything in one controller, and then include require controller_name at the top of the other controllers and just calling what i needed. In the future yoka, you may find more luck getting your answers accepted if you can more clearly explain what you mean. Note that your response to my comment didn't answer the question, and just saying 'in another class' doesn't specify what sort of class I'm looking for. As a beginner to rails, your answer directed me where to look, but didn't really answer the question.

Comment: In future pedalpete you may find more luck getting your questions answered if you can explain more clearly what you need.  Note that yoka's response could have been more detailed, but you can not fault him for your lack of understanding of basic OOP principals like inheritance.